# Issues with JSON deserialization

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, json.net

I know there are a lot of answers related to this, however, I am unable to parse the response.

This is my JSON that I get back from `wrGETURL.OpenRead(sURL)`:

```
{
    "sessionKey": "TFtG+pGZ0cl0TuUbItWGy9xb9RyoPKGlY2EUF/nHe"
}
```

This is my JSON that I get back from `getcall.OpenRead(sURL)`:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "OK",
    "total": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "domain": "emailsecautomate.co",
            "status": "Active",
            "order_date": "2017-04-26",
            "service": "Email Security",
            "company_name": "some name",
            "address1": "1 somewhere",
            "address2": null,
            "city": "somecity",
            "state": null,
            "country": "some country",
            "post_code": null,
            "telephone": null,
            "email": null,
            "po_number": null,
            "licenses": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I comment out the line `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TotalResponse)(st)` and output `st` to a `MessageBox` this is my JSON:

[image: screenshot for json response]

As you can see it's fine. However if I comment back in that line I get the following error:

> 401 Unauthorized

This is my full code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    user = username.Text
    pwd = password.Text

    'MessageBox.Show(savedUser)
    If savedUser IsNot Nothing AndAlso savedUser = "-9999" Then
        Dim sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('" & user & "','" & pwd & "')"
        mobjHost.SetSQL(sqlStatement)
    End If

    Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd))

    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://xxx.xxx/partners/auth"

    Dim wrGETURL As New WebClient()

    wrGETURL.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)

    Try
        Dim data As Stream = wrGETURL.OpenRead(sURL)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
        Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IDictionary)(s)
        'This line with/without ToString gives the error "objectreference is not set to an instance of Object"
        Dim sessionKey = jsonResult.Item("sessionKey").ToString
        'Not calling the function for now As even session key gives the same issue
        'MessageBox.Show(sessionKey) This shows the sessionKey and everything is fine if this is used
        'Me.getCustomers(sessionKey)
        wrGETURL.Dispose()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Function getCustomers(ByVal sKey As String)
    Dim st As String = ""
    Dim getcall As New WebClient()
    getcall.Headers.Add("USER", user)
    getcall.Headers.Add("KEY", sKey)
    getcall.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    Dim sURL = "https://xxx.xxx/partners/customers"
    Try
        Dim data As Stream = getcall.OpenRead(sURL)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
        st = reader.ReadToEnd()

        theResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TotalResponse)(st)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

These are my classes for the JSON response:

```
Public Class TotalResponse
    Public success As String
    Public message As String
    Public total As String
    Public data As List(Of CustomerInfo)
End Class


Public Class CustomerInfo
    Public domain As String
    Public status As String
    Public order_date As String
    Public service As String
    Public company_name As String
    Public address1 As String
    Public address2 As String
    Public city As String
    Public state As String
    Public country As String
    Public post_code As String
    Public telephone As String
    Public email As String
    Public po_number As String
    Public licenses As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) for your `WebClient` and `StreamReader` objects:

> Managed resources are disposed of by the .NET Framework garbage collector (GC) without any extra coding on your part. You do not need a Using block for managed resources. However, you can still use a Using block to force the disposal of a managed resource instead of waiting for the garbage collector.

Please also look at turning [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) which will help you write better code:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

I would also look at using the `JsonSerializationException` within your `Catch` rather than a general `Exception`.

With your method `getCustomers`, consider changing it into a function and returning `TotalResponse`.

Lastly consider only declaring variables *if* they are needed and *only* when they are required. This helps with reducing the amount of code and with the workflow of your code. This can be particular useful for debugging.

With these changes your code would look something like this:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sessionKey As String = ""
    Using wb As New WebClient()
        Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd))
        wb.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)

        Dim data As Stream = wb.OpenRead("https://xxx.xxx/partners/auth")
        Using reader As New StreamReader(data)
            Try
                Dim result As IDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IDictionary)(Await reader.ReadToEndAsync())

                sessionKey = result.Item("sessionKey").ToString()
            Catch ex As JsonSerializationException
                'handle
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    If Not sessionKey = "" Then
        Dim theResponse As TotalResponse = getCustomers(sessionKey)
    End If

End Sub

Private Async Function getCustomers(ByVal sKey As String) As TotalResponse

    Dim returnResponse As New TotalResponse

    Using wb As New WebClient()
        wb.Headers.Add("USER", user)
        wb.Headers.Add("KEY", sKey)
        wb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

        Dim data As Stream = wb.OpenRead("https://api-dev.theemaillaundry.net/partners/customers")
        Using reader As New StreamReader(data)
            Try
                returnResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TotalResponse)(reader.ReadToEndAsync())
            Catch ex As JsonSerializationException
                'handle
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    Return returnResponse

End Function
```

I've also noted your SQL is open to SQL injection. It's outside the scope of this question however consider using SQL parameters. I'm not familiar with `mobjHost.SetSQL` so unfortunately I can't advise in this area.